# Manually ordering trigger firing in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have table A and 4 row level Before Insert triggers on table A.
what would be order of trigger firing?
Is it runtime decided?
can we order trigger firing e.g. Trigger 2 then Trigger 4 then Trigger 3 then Trigger 1?

Comment: The `FOLLOWS` answer that @EatAPeach suggests is the way to do what you are literally asking.  From an application architecture standpoint, however, it would almost certainly make more sense to have a single row-level before insert trigger that called 4 separate procedures that do whatever the 4 triggers would otherwise do.  Having multiple triggers of the same type makes sense in vanishingly few situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS99985), all triggers of the same type before executing triggers of a different type. If there are multiple triggers of the same type on the same table, the database chooses an arbitrary, unpredictable order.

If you want it to execute in a definite order you should use [FOLLOWS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#CJADJGIF) clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER2
BEFORE INSERT
ON TEST_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER4
BEFORE INSERT
ON TEST_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
FOLLOWS TRIGGER2

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER3
BEFORE INSERT
ON TEST_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
FOLLOWS TRIGGER4
```

Comment: Note that `FOLLOWS` only exists starting in 11.1.  Prior to that, there is no way to declaratively force triggers of the same type to run in a particular order.